# How to use the predicate "assert" in a predicate

Tags: prolog

I have a problem I want a code Prolog for that I will generate new predicate with the predicate "assert" but I want to use the result of my predicate .
i have a predicate that counts the number of element of a list here is it 
and I have to make a new predicate that will add me a new predicate using the predicate "assert" in my knowledge base calling to the predicate "creat_nbStation" who will use the 2 "assert" and "compte" for exemple i have creat_nbStation(L) and L is a Liste it will add me in my knowledge base a new predicate it's nb_Station(L,25) using assert predicate .

thank you for the help.
this is my predicate for counting the number of elements of a list and it worka perfectly

```
compte([],0).
compte([_|R],N) :- compte(R,N1), N is N1+1, N>0.
```

Comment: Prolog's "assert" built-in predicate is often used to emulate global variables, allowing intermediate results of calls to be "saved" from the forgetful effects of backtracking.  Perhaps you want to do something of this kind with dynamic predicate `nb_Station/2`.  However I'm finding it hard to understand the specific question you ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite difficult to figure out what exactly you are looking for, but I must say it does look very much like homework assignment. Is this what you are looking for?

```
create_nbStation(L) :- compte(L, N), assert(nbStation(L, N)).
```

Comment: Yes Thank you very much man it's work perfectly its what i wanted .   I wanted to use assert for addading the new predicat nb_station in my knowledge base thank you very much thank you

Comment: And Now i try to use this for addading all the station that i have woith findall i explain more  for exemple i have 10 station and i want to use that creat_nbStation(L) for all the station that i have so i put like that but it's make me an error        creat_nbStation(findall(ligne(L,_,_,_)):-compte(L,N),assert(nbStation(L,N)).  can you help me???i want to use that for i will not have to call all time to the fonction with findall he will makes alone thank you

Comment: Now i am trying to do that for all my station i explain more i have 1à station station(Name,type,Liste) and i am trying to use this creat_nbStation for all my stations so i used the findall but when i make like that "creat_nbStation(findall(station(X,_,L)):-compte(L,N),assert(nbStation(X,N))  but it don't work its make me an error ???